# 5 numbers in an empty binary tree

Tags: binary-search-tree, inorder

You insert 5 numbers to an empty binary search tree. The numbers output from applying in-order scan algorithm to this tree are:

```
4 7 8 9 11
```

and the numbers output from applying level-order scan algorithm to the tree are

```
7 4 9 8 11
```

What is(are) leaf node value(s) in the tree after you delete node 4?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be a pure copy+paste of a homework assignment.  It does not follow the guidance for homework questions given in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: it would just be be 11 since that's the largest number and it will be the last value in the tree to not have any children.

Comment: You could always just draw it out. If the larger number is larger than the root, then it belongs to the right of it and etc. The only question I have is, if 7 is the root in this case. If that holds true, then 11 would be the leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Now this will be a very rough sketch to do, but bear with me. So you gave me a field of numbers, and I'm just assuming 7 is the root. so it goes like this.

```
   7
 /   \
4     8
       \
        9
         \
          11
```

In this case, 4 and 11 would be the leaf nodes. Now after you delete 4 from it.

```
   7
    \
     8
      \
       9
        \
         11
```

Leaving 11 to be the leaf since it has no children.